# Android google maps. Add marker by address

Tags: android, google-maps

I added map in android application and want to add marker on map by address. It is possible?
I already tried to get long and lat with `Geocoder`, but there I get error `Service not Available`.

my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(event.getPlace(), 20);
            System.out.println(addresses);
//          for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) { // MULTIPLE MATCHES
//
//              Address addr = addresses.get(i);
//
//              double latitude = addr.getLatitude();
//              double longitude = addr.getLongitude(); // DO SOMETHING WITH
//                                                      // VALUES
//
//              System.out.println(latitude);
//              System.out.println(longitude);
//
//          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can you post what you've tried so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Your problem seems to be the geocoding part.

The problem with your use of Geocoder is that it requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework, as mentioned in the [Android API for Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). You should use `geocoder.isPresent()` to check if this functionality is available. If it is not, you cannot use this method.

Geocoding can alternatively be done with Google Maps using a URL, as  described in [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index). For example (you need an API key):

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY

Giving a result that can be parsed to retrieve latitude and longitude for your marker.

Comment: So if geocoder is not present, what can we do? How can show destination amrker on map?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde you could use the URL I suggested as an alternative. This has no Android API requirements.

Comment: Why Geocoder is not in support library!? Do you know?

Comment: Because the phone manufacturer did not create its own implementation of it. It is not part of the core android framework.

Answer (score 20):

Create a method to convert address to LatLng:

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress)
{
    Geocoder coder= new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try
    {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if(address==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p1;

}
```

then ,

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);      

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
  LatLng address = getLocationFromAddress(this, yourAddressString(eg. "Street Number, Street, Suburb, State, Postcode");
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(address).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(address));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

fun getLocationByAddress(context: Context, strAddress: String?): LatLng? {
    val coder = Geocoder(context)
    try {
        val address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5) ?: return null
        val location = address.first()
        return LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e, "getLocationByAddress")
    }
    return null
}
```